# jquery animation move one class to within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**This is the edit of the question to add the following....
animating an object with jquery simply as follows.....**

```
$("div").animate({left: '250px'});
```

**But it would be ideal if instead of left:'250'px it could be the target**

```
div/class something like this....
$("div").animate({'.title-area-main'});
```

So this question relates to a bit of html , I have a this class within a div called wrapper ....

```
<div class="logo"><img src="images/mthc/logo-main.png" height="150px" width="420px"></div>
```

it is defined in css as ....

```
#wrapper {
left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width:720px;
  height:300px;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
  z-index : 5001;
}
.logo{

  float:left;
  width:60%; 
  z-index : 5005;
}
```

the destination of the class "logo" is to this part of the html page....

```
 <a href="index.html" class="tile-area-title fg-white small" alt="musability logo"><img src="images/mthc/logo.png"></a>
```

and the css styling for this comes with the class "title-area-title" as per the a href link ....

```
.metro .tile-area .tile-area-title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 260px;
  border: 0 ;
  height: 120px;
  width: 800px;

}
```

I know I could use some really cool css3 animation tween to move the logo into place of the a tag.  that would be great if I am using internet explorer version 50000  ... **so I am basically looking for a jquery way of doing this and currently have no experience of jquery animation if even possible.  Any advice would be really helpful.**

Comment: "that would be great if I am using internet explorer version 50000" :D I'm sorry though, your question is unclear.

Comment: Have you tried [JQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/)?

Comment: i was exagerating the fact that not all browsers support css3

Comment: JQueryUI doesn't seem to have a widget for moving an item from one place to another at a glance

Comment: `translate(20px,20px)` will move an element `20px` on `x` and `y` coordinates. You can use css transitions to add a nice animation to it.

Comment: the point is to move away from css as it isn't universally compatible

Comment: $("div").animate({left: '250px'});  is the best answer so far

Comment: although it would be great if instead of left:'250px' it was the target div/class

Comment: targeting a class would be pointless since a class can occur more than one time in a page. But you could target a div with his id, take his coordinates and animate with those.

Comment: sounds like a plan , can you give an example of this ?

Comment: see my answer for the code to get the element's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an element's position :

```
   function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;

            while (element) {
                xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
            return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
        }
```

Then you call it like this :

```
 var y = getPosition(document.getElementById('mydivID')).y;
 var x = getPosition(document.getElementById('mydivID')).x;
```

Comment: actually i was going to throw the function into a current timer function so when it completes it simply performs the animation ... so far i have this ...   $("div").animate({left: '250px'});

Comment: seems like a lot of hastle as opposed to just performing the animation to just move to the same top and left margin position of the destination class

Comment: then do 
 $("#divid").animate({left:$('#destinationid').position().left,top:$('#destinationid').position().top});

Comment: that might work , i think i might stick with the left and top px until i test it on some stupid browser and it doesn't work ... .i am still branding your answer as correct and voting you up though , if you could do the same on my question that would be great thanks for the help.